# FailedRequest server error 520 when sending message using PyTextNow

Tags: python

Over the summer, I was successfully using the PyTextNow python library to send text messages from my raspberry pi to my phone with python. I stopped using it for a while, around a month. When I tried to use it again, my phone number on TextNow had expired and I was given new one. Since then, I have been unable to use my previous code even though I made all the needed adjustments for the new phone number. I get error that looks like this: FailedRequest: Could not send message. server return a Server error. Request Failed. Status Code: 520

Here is my code

```
import pytextnow as pytn

client = pytn.Client(#username#, #connect.sid#)

client.send_sms("phone #", "Hello")
```

I have verified that the username, connect.sid cookie, and phone number are all correct numerous times. I also set up a second TextNow account, modifying the code with the new username and connect.sid values, and got the same error. I know that I am connecting to the correct account because the client.get_unread_messages() function will pull up the correct messages. To my knowledge, it is only the send message function that is not working. Any help that would enable me to send sms messages again with PyTextNow, or a better way to send and read messages in python, would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can use Twilio - they give you a free account with a $20 credit. And messages are pretty cheap when you run out.

Comment: Don't you also need to give it the CSRF?